# javascript for-loop multidimensional array "cannot read property length of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array called strings, for example:

```
[['10','-','-','-','-','-','-','7','-'],
['-','12','-','14','-','-','11','-','-'],
['-','-','8','-','-','10','-','-','-']]
```

I am trying to use for loops to read through the array, but I need it to read the 0 index of all three inner-arrays, then the 1 index of all three, etc ([0][0], [1][0], [2][0], [0][1], etc).

Here is the for-loop structure I have set up inside a function:

```
      var z = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < strings[z].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
          if (strings[j][i] != '-') {
              notes.push(strings[j][i] + "-");
          }
        }
        z++;
      }
```

I get an error in the console: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on the line of my first loop (i < strings[z].length). I'm fairly new to javascript but I would think that if I define variable z globally outside of the loop I would be able to use it in my loop condition. Can anyone help me and let me know why strings[z] is undefined, and if there is another/better method of looping through the array in the pattern I need?

Thanks in advance.

*edited to add quotes around each array value (this is how it is in my code)

Comment: You'll need to quote the `-` so "-".

Comment: One problem is that your array is not all strings.  You have unquoted hyphens all through that array.

Comment: Sorry, I left out some code/details to simplify, but the array actually does has quotes around each hyphen and number

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = [
    [10,'-','-','-','-','-','-',7,'-'],
    ['-',12,'-',14,'-','-',11,'-','-'],
    ['-','-',8,'-','-',10,'-','-','-']
]

// get the length of the longest array
var maxLength = Math.max.apply(null, strings.map(function(e) { return e.length }));

var notes = [];
for (var j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
    strings.forEach(function(iString) {
        // the undefined takes care of shorter arrays
        if (iString[j] !== undefined && iString[j] !== '-')
            notes.push(iString[j] + "-");
    });

console.log(notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var strings = [['10', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '7', '-'],
    ['-', '12', '-', '14', '-', '-', '11', '-', '-'],
    ['-', '-', '8', '-', '-', '10', '-', '-', '-']]
;

var buffer = [];

for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < strings[i].length; j++) {
        if (buffer[j] == undefined) buffer[j] = [];
        buffer[j].push(strings[i][j]); 
    }
}

// now, strings[i][j] => buffer[j][i]

notes = [];

for (i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < buffer[i].length; j++) {
        if (buffer[i][j] != '-') notes.push(buffer[i][j] + '-');
    }
}

console.log(notes);
```

results:

```
["10-", "12-", "8-", "14-", "10-", "11-", "7-"]
```